# Is there an equivalent of System.Diagnostics.EventLog for C++?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, event-log

I need to change the parameters of the Windows Event Log from a C++ code, and namely what is available via the [System.Diagnostics.EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) class in C#. I need to read and later possibly modify the following properties:

- [MaximumKilobytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.maximumkilobytes.aspx)
- [OverflowAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.overflowaction.aspx)
- [MinimumRetentionDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.minimumretentiondays.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the [setting to the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

MaximumKilobytes->MaxSize

OverflowAction&MinimumRetentionDays->Retention

Comment: Thanks. It will do what I need. One question though. To change 'MaxSize' and 'Retention' values for the "Application" branch, all I need is to write them into the 'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application' registry key, right? Do they take effect immediately?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by getting and setting values in the registry.  Microsoft has [pretty detailed documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on this one. You would be interested in `MaxSize` and `Retention` values.